# Grouping [Union All] result from multiple columns SQL query

Tags: sql-server, group-by, union

I have a deal-table as below (more columns exists). I have been trying to use [Union] in my SQL query but when the value in dealContributor1ACV is the same as in dealContributor2ACV, the sum seems to exclude it. (dcA)

| dealContributor1 | dealContributor2 | dealContributor1ACV | dealContributor2ACV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dcA | dcD | 50000 | 50000 |
| dcC | dcA | 20000 | 12000 |
| dcA | dcC | 10000 | 17000 |
| dcD | dcB | 15000 | 11000 |

Looking for a query resulting in the below structure.

| dealContributor | dealContributorACV |
| --- | --- |
| dcA | 72000 |
| dcB | 11000 |
| dcC | 37000 |
| dcD | 65000 |

Here is what I am using now.

```
SELECT s.deal_contributer1 as 'dealContributor',s.deal_contributer1_acv as 'goalCompletionACV', GETDATE() as 'date2a'
FROM [dbo].[DynPSCsPersonGoals_20-21] g inner join [dbo].[HubspotDeal] s on g.email = s.deal_contributer1 WHERE s.Stage = 'closedwon' AND s.CloseDate >= '2020-09-01' AND s.CloseDate < '2021-01-01'
UNION
SELECT s.deal_contributer2 as 'dealContributor',s.deal_contributer2_acv as 'goalCompletionACV', GETDATE() as 'date2a'
FROM [dbo].[DynPSCsPersonGoals_20-21] g inner join [dbo].[HubspotDeal] s on g.email = s.deal_contributer2 WHERE s.Stage = 'closedwon' AND s.CloseDate >= '2020-09-01' AND s.CloseDate < '2021-01-01'
ORDER by dealContributor
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to union then aggregate:

```
    SELECT contributor AS dealContributor, SUM(deal) AS dealContributorACV
FROM
(
    SELECT s.deal_contributer1 AS contributor, cast(s.deal_contributer1_acv as decimal) AS deal
    FROM [dbo].[DynPSCsPersonGoals_20-21] g
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[HubspotDeal] s ON g.email = s.deal_contributer1
    WHERE s.Stage = 'closedwon' AND
          s.CloseDate >= '2020-09-01' AND s.CloseDate < '2021-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.deal_contributer2, s.deal_contributer2_acv
    FROM [dbo].[DynPSCsPersonGoals_20-21] g
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[HubspotDeal] s ON g.email = s.deal_contributer2
    WHERE s.Stage = 'closedwon' AND
          s.CloseDate >= '2020-09-01' AND s.CloseDate < '2021-01-01'
) t
GROUP BY contributor;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine with one snag. If the values in the columns dealContributor1ACV and dealContributor2ACV is exactly the same the [UNION] is excluding the value. 

I.e. dealContributor1 (dcA) is sharing the contribution 50-50 with dealContributor2 (dcB) and they both have a value of 10000 in the dealContributorxACV columns . The sum for dcA is not picking up the 10000 connected to dcA.

Not sure if I am making sense but hopefully I do... :)

Comment: I'm using `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.

Comment: Yes, using only UNION will case issues instead if dealContributor1 have same value in dealContributor1ACV. Then the query will count the value only ones. 

I.e. If dcA have two 10000 values in column  dealContributor1ACV. It will only count it one time. So 10000 and not 20000.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Please _edit_ your data above and show the actual problem.

Comment: Ok, used your query and tried to clarify. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @tim-biegeleisen. It was a simple typo that caused the query to sum wrong. I edited the query changing a "1" to a "2" in the g.email = s.deal_contributer2 part.